# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, io

I'm new to python and networking, I trying to build simple socket program that send message to server using python but I got this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Chat\tcp_server.py",
> line 12, in 
> print('[*] Accepted connection from: ', addr, ' : ', data.decode())
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'decode'

This is my server code:

```
import socket 
bind_ip = "127.0.0.1"
bind_port = 7777
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))
server.listen(1)
print('[*] TCP Server Listening on:', bind_ip,' ',bind_port)
while True:
    client, addr = server.accept()
    server.setblocking(0)
    data = client.recvfrom(4096)
    print('[*] Accepted connection from: ', addr, ' : ', data.decode())
    data = 'Connected'
    client.send(data.encode(), addr)
    client.close()
```

This is client code:

```
import socket
target_host = "127.0.0.1"
target_port = 7777
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((target_host, target_port))
data = 'latihan pemograman socket'
client.send(data.encode('utf_8'))
respon = client.recv(4096)
print(respon.decode())
```

What do I do wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `recvfrom()` returns a tuple `(data, address)`. If you just need the data, use `recv()`.

Comment: `recvfrom()` is generally only used with datagram sockets, not streams, since each message can come from a different client.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should use `recv(4096)` instead of `recvfrom(4096)` because `recvfrom` returns a tuple of (ByteObject, Address).

`recvfrom` is usually used for UDP and gets exactly one message sent by `sendto`.